# Publishing an app on android market without download permission

Tags: android, google-play

Is there anyway of deploying an app on android market without letting people download it ? Something like the Apple Store behavior of blocking the download of the app until the release date or owner's will.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's anything like that. Why would you need that?

Comment: @Aleadam Because testing LVL properly is [impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365118/market-licensing-example-always-getting-licensed) otherwise. @user569873 +1 for the thoughtful question.

Answer (score 0):

It filters market results based on the type of device you have. Maybe you could set some of the things in the manifest in such a combination that a device that meets those requirements doesn't exist yet. That might filter your app out of all of the market search results. But I don't even know if that is possible, and when you wanted to "activate" it so that people could download it you'd have to upload an update with a new manifest. So it seems like you might as well just not upload it until you are ready. Why are you interested in having it set up this way?